# Precompiling assets failure, but ... app still works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm pushing an app to Heroku and I get the error

> Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation

Now, I expected the app to fail, but it is running fine (from what I can see) on Heroku. Is this something I should be concerned about, will it create problems down-the-road? Why is this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a read of http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar it covers most scenarios and why you may be seeing that error.